# Cat person in Star Trek crew animated series

Tags: star-trek, federation, star-trek-tas

I have vague memories of watching the *Star Trek* cartoon series in the early seventies.

The communications officer was a female cat person who used to purr when she said "Yes Captain".

Has there ever been, in all the live action *Star Trek* series and movies, an actual feline species who are members of the Federation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Yes, the species' name is [Caitian](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Caitian)

According to the wikia, they are a member of the Federation and has been serving in the Starfleet in:

- *Star Trek: The Animated Series* (Lieutenant M'Ress, the one you refer to)

[image: Lieutenant M'Ress]

- *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home* (Unnamed Admiral and Commodore)

[image: Unnamed Admiral]

- *Star Trek: Into Darkness* (the Caitian twins that have accompanied Captain James T. Kirk - in bed)

[image: the Caitian twins]

Comment: There were also the [Kzinti](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Kzinti) in TAS who were also felinoid, but they were non-Federation members.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I love the way that the Kzinti clothes and space suits have tubes for their tails. Getting your tail all the way down that must be quite tricky. Perhaps you tie some string to the end and pull it through. And how do you cope with the fur being pulled the wrong way as you do it?

Comment: @PaulJohnson Maybe the tubes can unroll, so you just wrap it around the tail?

Comment: They are also available as a playable race on Star Trek Online on the Federation side.

Comment: @PaulJohnson From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kzin) on Kzin: "Kzinti tails are naked and are similar in appearance to a rat's tail, and their noses are black." So, no fur to worry about.

Comment: There's nothing feline about the Star Trek: Into Darkness aliens except for the tails tacked onto otherwise unchanged human bodies, it seems.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, it has been confirmed by the showrunners :)

Comment: @EdmundDantes: Yes, they're Caitians. They're just not very feline anymore, so I'm not sure they qualify as an example of a feline species in this question.

Comment: Well, maybe. I should also alter the last example, because these two Caitians do not seem to be serving in Starfleet (and this is stated before the examples are given). But they seem to be serving the Captain, though :)